# exclude system users using egrep

Tags: bash, grep, solaris

I try to exclude all system users and try to get a real users list in Solaris 10. I tried both:

```
 egrep -v "root|daemon|bin|sys|adm|lp|uucp|nuucp|smmsp|listen|webservd|postgres|svctag|unknown|nobody|noaccess|nobody4|perl|sshd" /etc/passwd
```

and

```
cat /etc/passwd | egrep -v "root|daemon|bin|sys|adm|lp|uucp|nuucp|smmsp|listen|webservd|postgres|svctag|unknown|nobody|noaccess|nobody4|perl|sshd"
```

But both produced a null output. (No error message). So what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `passwd` entries include a shell field, which usually looks like `/bin/sh`, `/usr/bin/bash`, etc. You have included the sequence `bin` in your exclusion list (to try to exclude the `bin` user) and it is excluding every entry.

Try restricting the filtering, such as by requiring the match to start at the beginning of the line:

```
egrep -v "^(root|daemon|bin|sys|adm|lp|uucp|nuucp|smmsp|listen|webservd|postgres|svctag|unknown|nobody|noaccess|nobody4|perl|sshd)" /etc/passwd
```